# Redirect 301 só no caso de acesso direto ao arquivo

Tags: redirecionamento, mod-rewrite

Tenho um arquivo .zip numa pasta do meu servidor e não quero links externos diretos para ele, só através de um link no meu próprio site. Então criei um .htaccess na pasta do arquivo e coloquei:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?meudominio.com.br [NC]
RewriteRule \.(zip)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22605189/restricting-access-to-zip-files-from-other-domains-with-htaccess

Isso basicamente resolve o problema de link externo, mas:

1. Se alguém colar o link na barra de endereço e seguir, ainda consegue fazer o download? Como eu conseguiria bloquear também o acesso direto (sem referência)?
2. Como posso redirecionar esses links já distribuídos para um URL (como o do link original) em vez de mostrar a página de acesso proibido?

Comment: Referencia pode ser facilmente manipulado e assim burlado, essa é uma péssima estratégia de "segurança". Seria mais interessante trabalhar com sessão e/ou token, o que é amplo demais para eu responder aqui.

Comment: Sem problema, não é exatamente um arquivo pago ou de conteúdo sensível. A ideia é só dificultar a linkagem externa porque perco muitas visitas.

Comment: Não consegui compreender a segunda pergunta "Como posso redirecionar esses links já distribuídos para um url (como o do link original) em vez de mostrar a página de acesso proibido?"

Comment: 1) sim, consegue, e se bloquear o sem referência (primeiro RewriteCond) bloqueará acessos legítimos, fica pior ainda (é opção dos navegadores informar ou não a referência). 2) Não tem como. Se o arquivo pode ser acessado por link sem alguma espécie de login ou autenticação, não há como fazer bloqueio (apenas diminuir o número de acessos indevidos, que é o que você já fez). Esse assunto já foi  bastante abordado no site, sugiro usar a pesquisa. Se quer proteger, tire o arquivo da raiz de forma a não estar acessível diretamente, e crie um mecanismo de autenticação que repasse o arquivo.

Comment: Respondendo o Guilherme: quero dizer redirecionar o link para o arquivo (que já foi distribuído por aí) para a página de download. Posso fazer um 301, mas isso está redirecionando o link da própria página também, não só os externos.

Comment: Então está ocorrendo 2 redirecionamentos a partir de um primeiro link quando deveria ocorrer apenas um? Tá confuso, tá parecendo outro problema, por falar nisso acho que nem deveria usar 301, deveria usar 302, pq 301 é permanente e se você não sabe o que esta fazendo e fez algo de errado será obrigado a ficar limpando o cache e resetando mais algumas coisas.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode configurar uma flag na sua sessão também, não sei qual linguagem você está utilizando, mas por exemplo no PHP, na página de download você pode colocar um `$_SESSION['autorizadownload'] = true;` e na página de download do arquivo você pode ler essa flag.